# How to measure the size of a file without saving it on disk?

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm making a dump file of a postgres base. 
By using `pg_dump base > base.sql`, postgres creates the `base.sql` but until the process is not done, the file appears with 0 bytes. 
Is there a way to acess the size of the file to make a kind of progress bar?

I tried it with python with the os.stat() but it shows 0 bytes too:

```
>>> import os
>>> file = os.stat('base.sql')
>>> file.st_size
>>> 0L
```

Comment: For information, I'm using Ubuntu...

Comment: I don't think you can, until all the sectors of the HDD are occupied by the file.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Where do sectors and HDD come into this? Nothing in the question suggests that this is specifically for an HDD.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I didn't express myself correctly.

Comment: Whatever is writing to the file would have to figure that out in advance. Usual trick is to 'know' you are writing x lines out and use that.

Comment: Instead of just dumping to a file, you could pipe it through a program that just copies it along (like `cat`, but which you wrote to count bytes as they go across). Something like `pg_dump | progress >base.sql`. But you still won't know the final size until it's done.

Comment: If you need to keep the size down, consider piping the output through `gzip`. SQL can usually be heavily compressed, even on the CPU-cheap `gzip -1` level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One non-python option is to use the `pv` command line program ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)), which is available in the universe repository:

```
apt-get install pv
```

Now you can pipe through `pv` to get continuous updates on how much data has been written to the output file so far:

```
pg_dump base | pv > base.sql
```

Of course, `pv` has no way of knowing the final size in this case, so it will only display the amount of data piped so far. If you've got a guesstimate you may provide it with the `-s` argument, and you'll get a proper progress bar:

```
pg_dump base | pv -s 500M > base.sql
```

[Here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/open-source/command-line-hacks/pv-command-examples/) is a blog post I found with install instructions, examples and screenshots.

Comment: I think this is a good idea. Even don't knowing the full size of the base I with this pv I can see that postgres is working.
Thanks man... I'll implemment it and post the code here...

Comment: Here is the archive I made to people from my work use:
[link](https://gist.github.com/marlonjke/6113544)

Comment: @marlon-janke looks good, except 500 MB was just a number I plucked out of thin air. As you start using this program you'll probably home in on a better estimate for the final file size. :)

Comment: Yes I know, but the most bases are approximately 500Mb.
I'll find a way to take the full size of the base but now it'll be that way... thanks again

Comment: I modify the code. Now I make a connection before creating the dump and get the approximately size of the base.
Here is it: [link]https://gist.github.com/marlonjke/6113544

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, until all the file has been written to the HDD.

In order to make a progress bar you have to know what is the space occupied at `100%` by the file. Only then, by using that number and the current space used by the file you're writing you can calculate the current percentage of written file.